# no module named HelloTemplate Import Error

Tags: python, django

i am getting an import error. it says there is no module named HelloTemplate. but there is a HelloTemplate class which i have imported in the urls.py file.
"login" is my django app name.

this is my views.py file.

```
#from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import  HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
# Create your views here.
def hello(request):
    name='Zeeshan'
    html="<html><body> hi this is %s.</body></html>" %name
    return HttpResponse(html)

def hello_template(request):
    name='zeeshan'
    t=get_template('hello.html')
    html=t.render(Context({'name':name}))
    return HttpResponse(html)

class HelloTemplate (TemplateView):
        template_name="hello_class.html"

        def get_context_data(self,  **kwargs):
            context=super(HelloTemplate,  self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context["name"] = "zee"
            return context
```

this is url.py file..

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from login.views import HelloTemplate

urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^hello/$', 'login.views.hello'), 
    url(r'^hello_template/$', 'login.views.hello_template'), 
    url(r'^hello_class_view/$','HelloTemplate.as_view()'), 
]
```

here is the error report while running on local server.

```
ImportError at /hello_class_view/

No module named HelloTemplate

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello_class_view/
Django Version:     1.8.4
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named HelloTemplate

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py in        import_module, line 37
Python Executable:  /home/grayhat/Documents/python/projects/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/home/grayhat/Documents/python/projects/myapp',
 '/home/grayhat/Documents/python/projects/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/grayhat/Documents/python/projects/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/grayhat/Documents/python/projects/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/grayhat/Documents/python/projects/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/grayhat/Documents/python/projects/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/grayhat/Documents/python/projects/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/grayhat/Documents/python/projects/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/grayhat/Documents/python/projects/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/grayhat/Documents/python/projects/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Mon, 21 Sep 2015 08:06:38 +0000
```

Comment: Your views.py and urls.py in the same directory?

Comment: no both are in different directory.

Comment: views.py is in "login" directory and urls.py is in "myapp" directory.

Comment: btw, you need to import both names from `login.views`: `from login.views import hello_template, HelloTemplate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The snippet in **urls.py** `'HelloTemplate.as_view()'` should be `HelloTemplate.as_view()`. This is, without quotes. You can see more on referencing Class based views [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/#subclassing-generic-views).

Comment: Also you can write `hellotemplate = HelloTemplate.as_view()` in views.py and `url(r'^hello_class_view/$', 'login.views.hellotemplate')` in urls.py

Comment: @user2172884 can do and thanks for your feedback. However, I think for conventions sake and risk of confusing OP, it's best to stick to the way it is documented on django's website.